# Node module fbgraph: will this deal well with lots of users?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to integrate the facebook Graph API into my NodeJS server. Right now, [the fbgraph module](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph) looks like a really simple and straightforward solution to my needs. My only concern is the way that fbgraph sets accessTokens for facebook users. As per the api description, the accessToken is set as follows:

```
graph.setAccessToken(access_token);
```

My one worry is as follows: If my site gains a lot of popularity and I have hundreds of requests to the facebook graph per second, I'll have to set the (what seems to be) global variable for each user that I want to interact with. Is there any chance that the graph api can have the access token set for a user before the previous user's api request is taken care of? Intuitively I feel like I should use a module that includes the access token with each individual API call, but maybe that isn't necessary...

Can anybody clarify as to whether or not my worries have any justification?

Best,
Sami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid concern, and in fact there has been [an issue raised about it](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph/issues/5):

> **criso commented**:
>
> doh! good point. I'm thinking that this should probably be added as middleware so that the request is always tied in with the session. Not sure when I'll be able to implement this. If you have time, go nuts!

then

> **criso commented**:
>
> Actually, instead of doing this:
>
> ```
> graph.get("/me", req.session.access_token, function(err, data) {
>     console.log(data);
> });
> ```
>
> Just do:
>
> ```
> graph
>   .setAccessToken(req.session.access_token)
>   .get("/me", function(err, data) {
>       console.log(data);
>   });
> ```

Comment: fgGraph has been updated to account for this: https://github.com/criso/fbgraph#to-use-a-specific-access-token-for-a-particular-request